# Is the regular expression syntax for FART documented anywhere?

Tags: command-line, regex, find-and-replace

I'm trying to use FART (find and replace text) to search for character sequences and I'm using both the `--c-style` option (so that I can use `\x2F` to represent a forward slash), and also `--word`, so I can use regular expressions.  However I can't get regular expressions to work.

E.g.

```
fart --line-number --ignore-case --preview --c-style --word *.pas "\x2F\x2F.*hello"
```

should match and print out the lines:

```
// hello
// well, hello there
```

- given my understanding of RegExp syntax (`.` matches any character, `*` means "zero or more occurrences of the preceding character"), but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know if the syntax of regular expressions is documented? (or maybe `--c-style` and `--word` are incompatible?).

** EDIT **

I should point out that the utility `findstr` also does the job I want, and probably supports regex's properly, but the one really useful thing about `FART` is that it returns the number of hits in `%ErrorLevel%`.  `findstr` only returns a "found" or "not found" in the return code.

Comment: Hmmmm.  The help says `-w, --word          Match whole word (uses C syntax, like grep)` which sort of implies that it handles regex's.  I'll experiment some more based on your comments

Comment: Just tested it.  Shows no signs of implementing regex's with or without the `--c-style` or `--word` options - i.e. all combinations.

Comment: Well that eliminates that as be the issue. I'll try further testing when I get a chance with the tool.

Comment: Just received advice from the FART sourceforge page that "wildcards are not supported, sorry".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The FART folks at SourceForge have confirmed that there is no support for regular expressions.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, if not this answer maybe better as a comment

Comment: yep, I wasn't sure if 'no" was really a valid answer, but I figured if somebody sees a question and sees that it hasn't been answered, they might continue looking elsewhere needlessly, whereas if they see the question *is* answered, they are more likely to take a look and discover that the syntax isn't documented.