# Using FART, how would you search through files matching only a specific known set of file extensions (e.g., .*php|*.html)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, regex

Using [FART](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/), how would you search only from a known set of file extensions (e.g., like this REGEX `.*\.(php|js|html?|css|txt|htaccess)$`) without using the `*.*` catch-all, to process a find-and-replace-text command?

I have already searched [this blog](https://emtunc.org/blog/03/2011/farting-the-easy-way-find-and-replace-text/), from 2011, but cannot find an example close enough to modify.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1364789/fart-replace-mulitple-extensions) is 100% unrelated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the regular expression syntax for FART documented anywhere?](https://superuser.com/questions/1112611/is-the-regular-expression-syntax-for-fart-documented-anywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer : [Is the regular expression syntax for FART documented anywhere?](https://superuser.com/a/1127064/557920)

---

***The FART folks at SourceForge have confirmed that there is no support for regular expressions.***

But i think you can do it easily with **Powershell** that supports Regex